# Applying UPPER() function in SELECT FROM VIEW or in CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view

I have a view in Snowflake:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES(
    ID,
    CODE,
    VARID
) as
    Select  
      ID::string as ID,
      CODE::string as CODE,
      VARID::string as VARID,
    From 
        (SELECT ID, CODE, VARID FROM TABLE_A) union all
        (SELECT ID, CODE, VARID FROM TABLE_B) union all
        (SELECT ID, CODE, VARID FROM TABLE_C);
```

I need to select the `varid` from the view in my code but I need to convert the values to upper-case.

```
SELECT UPPER(varid) AS varid FROM DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES
```

However, this makes the query scan the whole table to apply the UPPER() function to every row which increases the bytes scanned. Instead of applying the UPPER() function when selecting from the view like above, is it better to apply the UPPER() function inside the view instead so that I don't need to apply the UPPER() function every time I select from the view.

```
SELECT varid FROM DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES(
    ID,
    CODE,
    VARID
) as
    Select  
      ID::string as ID,
      CODE::string as CODE,
      VARID::string as VARID,
    From 
        (SELECT ID, CODE, UPPER(VARID) AS VARID FROM TABLE_A) union all
        (SELECT ID, CODE, UPPER(VARID) AS VARID FROM TABLE_B) union all
        (SELECT ID, CODE, UPPER(VARID) AS VARID FROM TABLE_C);
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @nbk Is it better to apply the UPPER() function inside the view instead of applying the UPPER() function when selecting from outside the view?

Comment: in side the view, but why save them in lower case anyway?

Comment: Actually, I don't believe it matters if its in the view or outside of the view.  When the query is executed, the profiler will determine when to best apply the `UPPER()`.  The only reason you'd put it in the view is if you never want anybody using the view to be able to see the data in it's current case.  If you want to leave the option open to users, then leave it out of the view.  Your statement about "scanning the whole table" is also a bit confusing and not really how Snowflake works.

Comment: @nbk Thank you for your comment. I have decided to save the data in the correct case rather than applying the UPPER() function to maximize efficiency.

Comment: @MikeWalton Thank you for your comment. I have decided to save the data in the correct case rather than applying the UPPER() function to maximize efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Mike already pointed out important points: If you use UPPER in the view definition, then it will impact all users who will access this view.

About the performance, I think it only matters if you will search data using the varid column, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES where varid = 'XYZ';
```

In this case, if you use UPPER, then Snowflake will need to apply the UPPER function when filtering the values, and it may make a negative impact on the performance. On the other hand, if you aren't sure about the case of the data, and you need to do your searches using UPPER, then it's not important to define it on VIEW or on your query:

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE.PUBLIC.ALL_TABLES where UPPER(varid) = 'XYZ';
```

If this column will only be used on projection (no filtering), it doesn't matter where the UPPER is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have decided to save the data in the correct case rather than applying the UPPER() function to maximize efficiency.